# Updating Output List

Tags: python, list

I created the following code:

```
def color_filter(x):
for i in x:
    for n, pix in enumerate(i):
        new = ((pix[0]+pix[1]+pix[2])//3, 0, 0), (0, (pix[0]+pix[1]+pix[2])//3, 0), (0, 0, (pix[0]+pix[1]+pix[2])//3)
        i[n] = new
return x
```

where
`x = [[(84, 0, 153), (84, 0, 153), (84, 0, 153)], [(177, 219, 255), (5177, 219, 255), (177, 219, 255)]]`

I want the code to output
`[[(79, 0, 0), (0, 79, 0), (0, 0, 79)], [(217, 0, 0), (0, 217, 0), (0, 0, 217)]]`
but it outputs
`[[((79, 0, 0), (0, 79, 0), (0, 0, 79)), ((79, 0, 0), (0, 79, 0), (0, 0, 79)), ((79, 0, 0), (0, 79, 0), (0, 0, 79))], [((217, 0, 0), (0, 217, 0), (0, 0, 217)), ((217, 0, 0), (0, 217, 0), (0, 0, 217)), ((217, 0, 0), (0, 217, 0), (0, 0, 217))]]`
instead. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the innter list. Find the comments inside the code

```py
def color_filter(x):
    for index, pixels in enumerate(x):
        first_value = pixels[0]
        avg = sum(first_value)//3
        x[index] = [(avg, 0, 0), (0, avg, 0), (0, 0, avg)]
#         for n, pix in enumerate(i):
#             new = ((pix[0]+pix[1]+pix[2])//3, 0, 0), (0, (pix[0]+pix[1]+pix[2])//3, 0), (0, 0, (pix[0]+pix[1]+pix[2])//3)
#             print(i[n])
#             i[n] = new
# you don't need to return since you are modifying the original list
#    return x

x = [[(84, 0, 153), (84, 0, 153), (84, 0, 153)], [(177, 219, 255), (177, 219, 255), (177, 219, 255)]]
color_filter(x)

print(x)
```

```
[[(79, 0, 0), (0, 79, 0), (0, 0, 79)], [(217, 0, 0), (0, 217, 0), (0, 0, 217)]]
```